# Can not output regex array with echo. Notice: Undefined offset: 0. How to fix it?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$from= "You can win $200,000 tonight.";
$output = preg_match("/\$[\d\,]+/", $from, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

This is not working. It gives me this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0

I want to output the "$200,000".

Thanks in advance with any help.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$output = preg_match("/\\$[\d\,]+/", $from, $matches);
```

You have to escape twice the $ symbol with double \

http://ideone.com/digsP

Answer (score 1):

You shot yourself into your knee with the double quotes of the regex. Try this one:

```
$from= "You can win $200,000 tonight.";
if(preg_match("/\$[\d\,]+/", $from, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

You see, no match. You have to escape twice, once for the string and once for the regex engine:

```
$from= "You can win $200,000 tonight.";
if(preg_match("/\\\$[\d\,]+/", $from, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

HTH,
 CK

Comment: Or just switch to using single quotes... `'/(\$[\d,]+)/'` and add the capturing group `()` so there's something to go into $matches.

Comment: $matches consists always of the whole match, regardless of the back references.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape $ twice.

```
$output = preg_match("/\\$[\d\,]+/", $from, $matches);
```